# How to refresh a page automatically after user make changes in Flutter, without router's navigate?

Tags: flutter, callback

I wrote a widget to show a home screen with some list data, which should be loaded from database, like this:

```dart
class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {

  //create a new data and inser into database
  Future<void> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return await showDialog(context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context,setState){
            return AlertDialog(
              //form to get information
              content: Form(),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                      //..insert to database
                      toast("create finished!!");
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      //I used to use navigate to refresh this page to load data,but it's 
                        too boring
                      //router.navigateTo(context,'index',transition:TransitionType.fadeIn );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...


    return Scaffold(
      body: makeBody,
      floatingActionButton:FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: (){
          showInformationDialog(context).then((value) => null);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to achieve this: after user create a new data and clicks post, it can insert this data to database and, without refreshing page, using navigate directly, but a more moderate way. I don't know whether it's the Entering page's fault.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `setState((){});` to redraw the review after changing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `SetState` after you click post

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: (){
   setState(() {});                           
}),
```

**But why ?**

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

So if the state of the widget changes you can call setState to trigger a rebuild of the view and see immediately the changes implied by the new state.